# Run power supply wire through garage for security camera

Tags: garage-door

I need to run thin power supply wire that came with security camera through garage. I have bricks in front upper portion of garage but there is little garage eaves where I can mount the camera. I also see rubber strips running across and down the garage outside against which door sealed when closed. Could any one please help what is the best way to run wire without doing too much effort. Please refer to pictures for inside and outside of garage corner where I want to install camera. Thanks
Garage door [image: Garage door inside]

[image: Garage door outside]

Comment: I cannot see the eves  that would be the best location if you are mounting the camera up there.

Comment: I will be mounting it on white wooden shed ( I don't know what to call it)...It is about 8 inch wide in the second picture.

Comment: I added a new photo with arrow pointing to location of camera. This is about 8 inch wide shade.

Answer (score 2):

To help with terminology I've added some notes to one of your pictures showing the names I use for the parts. The rubber strip is a "weather seal" and the painted white wood is a "jamb."

[image]

You can drill horizontally into the jamb. You'll need a long drill bit for this; the hole may have to be 4-6 inches deep from the interior surface of the lumber on the wall. This bore is illustrated with the line segment marked "1".

Next, drill vertically up into the jamb as illustrated with line "2". If you've positioned the drill well the two holes will intersect and you'll have an L-shape passage through the wood.

The wire can be fed through. It may be necessary to feed something else through first -- a small/light gauge wire, a string, etc. Creativity is key here. For example, if you're trying to get string through the long horizontal bore but it hangs up on the rough wood, try inserting a drinking straw first and push the string through that. It'll get you to the far end of the hole where a small hook or tweezers may be able to grab the string.

Before drilling the actual door jamb tou could practice the technique on a scrap of lumber from somewhere. A home center, lumber yard, or construction site may have a piece they'll sell or give to you.

Comment: Thanks for terminology. Honestly I didn't know and it really help if you have right terms. So hole 1 should be from inside of garage that meet from the hole 2 vertically from jamb? Is that correct...Thanks.

Comment: I find fishing line handy with small holes that are not quite straight, if I can see light sometimes a piece of solid copper wire will make a gentle bend and use the line or wire as a pull. That is if the cable can’t be pushed through this works quite often.